# contents of %userprofile%\AppData\Local,roaming being randomly deleted

Tags: windows-7

I am actively using windows 7 laptop as normal, and get a weird error about an application not being able to find a file. Then find that all of my settings for MANY applications have been forgotten.

Investigated a bit more, what I discovered is that the contents of the %userprofile%\AppData\Local and %userprofile%\AppData\roaming folders (and who knows what else) are basically being cleared and reset to some default state (like, the only folder remaining inside was the microsoft folder...) while I am in the middle of using my computer...wtf

I was able to go to properties of these folders and use the "previous versions" tab to restore the folders to a few days ago from the last time system restore made a backup but there are still many other settings that I had to reset manually...for example all of my credentials in the windows credentials manager were deleted...

Also, this is the second time that this has happened on this computer! The first time was about a week ago. I couldn't think of any recent major software/hardware changes that I have made. I ran a full scan with windows defender and it didn't find anything. I looked in the windows event log but nothing stood out around the times that this random deletion event occurred...
Also checked HDD SMART and it is good:[image: Imgur][image: Imgur][image: Imgur]

This is very bizarre and concerning, I have never experienced anything like this happening before...
Does anyone have any idea about what could cause this? Is there some weird background process in windows that could decide to clear everything out? Is this kind of behavior something some malware might do?

I tried to google for this but coundn't really find anything, I wasn't even sure what to search for...

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Sorry, I should have update my post: I already checked S.M.A.R.T and it appears to be good, I will update it.